# Increment an IP address when the IP address is given in steps in python

Tags: python, ip-address

How do I increment the IP address in python when we have start_ip in `4 octets` format and the step also in 4 octet format.

Let's suppose I start with an IP address of `225.1.1.1`, and the step as `0.0.0.1` 
When I say next_ip = start_ip + step, it should actually evaluate the expand produce the result.
I know that the `ipaddr` module does this with just an addition, but that does not seem to work when the step is also given in the ipv4 format.

Any known steps to do this:

```
import ipaddr 
a = ipaddr.ipaddress('225.1.1.1')
b = a +1
```

This actually returns the desired result. but when increment like this:

```
b = a + 0.0.0.1 it does not seem to work.
```

Any known solutions for this?

Comment: ReadTheFineManual [ipaddress -teration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#iteration)

Comment: Why would anyone specify an increment in dotted-quad notation? Is this data you're getting from somewhere else? Do you ever expect to see something like `0.1.0.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this piece of code can add two 4 octets :

```
first = '192.168.0.4'
second = '0.0.0.1'
ipaddress.ip_address(first) + int(ipaddress.ip_address(second))
```

this will result in: `IPv4Address('192.168.0.5')`

Answer (score 1):

Not refined but works i guess, here is the python snippet

```
def increment_ip_addr(ip_addr):
    ip_arr = ip_addr.split('.')

    def increment_by_1(digit):
        return str(int(digit) + 1)

    if int(ip_arr[3]) > 254:
        ip_arr[3] = "1"
        if int(ip_arr[2]) > 254:
            ip_arr[2] = "1"
            if int(ip_arr[1]) > 254:
                ip_arr[1] = "1"
                if int(ip_arr[0]) > 254:
                    ip_arr[0] = "1"
                else:
                    ip_arr[0] = increment_by_1(ip_arr[0])
            else:
                ip_arr[1] = increment_by_1(ip_arr[1])
        else:
            ip_arr[2] = increment_by_1(ip_arr[2])
    else:
        ip_arr[3] = increment_by_1(ip_arr[3])
    print(f"for ip address: {ip_addr} The incremented ip is: {'.'.join(ip_arr)}")

[increment_ip_addr(ip_addr) for ip_addr in ['1.1.1.1', "1.1.1.255", "1.255.1.255", "255.255.255.255"]]
```

corresponding console output:

```
for ip address: 1.1.1.1 The incremented ip is: 1.1.1.2
for ip address: 1.1.1.255 The incremented ip is: 1.1.2.1      
for ip address: 1.255.1.255 The incremented ip is: 1.255.2.1  
for ip address: 255.255.255.255 The incremented ip is: 1.1.1.1
```

Let me know in case of optimized version